# Examples of bounded sequence with infinite sub sequential limits.

Tags: sequences-and-series

Can anyone please help me to find an "Examples of bounded sequence with infinite sub sequential limits."

Comment: A constant sequence is an easy example.

Comment: @MrToad Sir but a constant sequence has only one limit which is equal to all the sub-sequential limit. I am looking for a bounded sequence having infinitely different many sub-sequential limits. Suppose (-1)^n has only two sub-sequential limit namely "+1" and "-1" i.e only two sub-sequential limit but I want infinitely many.

Comment: A bijection from $\mathbb{N}$ to $\mathbb{Q}\cap[0,1]$?

Comment: Users delt3, angryavian and Mr Toad already provided nice examples. A much harder example is the sequence $\{ \sin n : n \in \Bbb{N} \}$. The set of limit points is all of the interval $[-1 ,1]$.

Answer (score 2):

\begin{array}{}
1
\\
1&1/2
\\
1 & 1/2 & 1/3
\\
1 & 1/2 & 1/3 & 1/4
\\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots
\end{array}
(Reading from left to right)

Answer (score 0):

Similar to angryavian's answer and expanding on delt3's comment,
You can enumerate all of the rationals in $[0,1]$. Then given any $1/n$ for $n \in \mathbb{Z} ^+$ (of which there are infinitely-many) there exists an infinite subsequence converging to that number.